# Problemas de acceso a variables con el FileReader

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Tengo declarada una variable en mi componente y quisiera acceder a ella dentro de un **onloadend** de un ***FileRead***. Les muestro mi código.

```
export class AdjuntarArchivoComponent implements OnInit {

      documentosAdjuntos: FicherosAdj[] = [];

      constructor() {
      }
     ngOnInit() {.....}

      myUploader(event) {
        for (let i = 0; i < event.files.length; i++) {
          (function (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = (e) => {
              this.documentosAdjuntos.push({file: file, original: false, arrayBytes: reader.result});
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          })(event.files[i]);
        }
        this.fileInput.clear();
      }
    }
```

Ese código me genera un error en esta linea ***this.documentosAdjuntos.push({file: file, original: false, arrayBytes: reader.result});***

Es el siguiente:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentosAdjuntos' of undefined
    at FileReader.reader.onloadend (main.bundle.js:12929)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:2931)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.bundle.js:112820)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:2930)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded (polyfills.bundle.js:2694)
    at FileReader.<anonymous> (polyfills.bundle.js:2672)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por un lado estas usando funciones flecha para no perder el contexto de `this` pero por el otro estas usando un IIFE que hace que dicho contexto se pierda. Puedes reescribir tu funcion de esta forma

```
myUploader(event) {
    for (let i = 0; i < event.files.length; i++) {
        // Asigna una variable en lugar de usar un IIFE
        const file = event.files[i];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = (e) => {
            this.documentosAdjuntos.push({file: file, original: false, arrayBytes: reader.result});
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
}
```

Solo asigna una variable para manipular tu fichero en lugar de usar un IIFE y ya debes tener el valor de `this` correcto.